# Obstacle Avoidance

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, avoid-obstacle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Im wroking on a Robot that do the mapping, I'm using UltraSonic Sensors, IMU and Hall Sensors From the BLDC Motor, Arduino Mega 2560 and ROS Kinetic.

The next step is the obstacle avoidance. So the question is:
**How can I do obstacle avoidance using Lasersan data ???**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276124/obstacle-avoidance/) by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2017-11-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-17**:\

> How can I do obstacle avoidance using Lasersan data ???

one important requirement: do you have a laser scanner or similar device? Ultrasonic sensors != laser scanners.

**Comment by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on 2017-11-17**:
I have 3 ultrasonic sensors, I converted it to a Laserscan

**Comment by [Syrine](https://answers.ros.org/users/41424/syrine/) on 2019-06-26**:
Hi,
I know the post is old but i have the same problem, did you manage to avoid obstacles using ultrasound sensors? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorials on Navigation stack would be the right place to start (http://wiki.ros.org/navigation). The turtlebot implementation is a good example to see gmapping and amcl in action (https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/indigo/turtlebot_navigation). Just remember that once you create a map, the path generation in that map is independent of the sensors.

---

Originally posted by [ninja777](https://answers.ros.org/users/32648/ninja777/) with karma: 101 on 2017-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1